# DefaultType PHP 5.5 (for files that do NOT have any extension, including ".php")

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, php5

How can I add PHP to deal with files that do not have any extension? Is there a "DefaultHandler" directive? In Apache 2.2.29, with PHP 5.5, the following does not work:

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php55
```

Neither of those two work. In Apache 2.2.21 with PHP 5.3, the first directive used to work without any glitches. Google has yielded nothing. Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ForceType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype), You have examples of usage in the manual page. Wrap the directive in `<FilesMatch REGEX>` block, with regular expression matching ie. files without a dot (thus not having an extension).

Anyway, consider leaving PHP files with proper extensions and using *mod_rewrite* for better looking URIs.

Comment: Thank you. ForceType is the perfect answer with None as an option for files with extensions. In the future we will probably just use PHP extension and use rewrite rules.